# How Do I set a cookie in fetch request?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am baffled by one particular problem. I am trying to set a cookie using the fetch api but I am unable to do so.

```
static deleteorder = (domain = "http://localhost:8080/pc", order) => {

  let cooks = "JSESSIONID=AFAFWEEVV2323GG";
  fetch(deleteorder, {
      method: `GET`,
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        "Content-type": `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
      },

    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.status);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
}
```

When The function runs and `200` is returned but the data remains the same meaning the order remains. Can one of you shed some light? I am in the beginner phase of learning the fetch api so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Content-type` is not meaningful in a `GET` request, it doesn't send any content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Fetch()` simply sends the current document's cookies, so just add the cookie to `document.cookie`.

```
static deleteorder = (domain = "http://localhost:8080/pc", order) => {

  document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=AFAFWEEVV2323GG";
  fetch(deleteorder, {
      method: `GET`,
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.status);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: ...because there is no other way(https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/349)

Comment: That's a polyfill, it should work with the native implementations.

Comment: Thanks mate @Barmar but I get an error Reference: document is not defined.

Comment: Are you running this in a browser?

Comment: Hey mate I’m using node.js @Barmar

Comment: Then this answer is totally wrong, it's for sending cookies from a browser.